# MSE always becomes 0 when training linear regression from scratch at 33th iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a multi-linear regression model from scratch on the Spotify 2023 dataset on Kaggle.

```
def min_max_scalar(df, col):
df[col] = (df[col] - min(df[col])) / (max(df[col]) - min(df[col]))
return df[col]

def mean_squared_error(actual, predicted):
return np.mean((actual - predicted) ** 2)

spotify_2023_data['streams'] = min_max_scalar(spotify_2023_data, 'streams')

X = spotify_2023_data[['in_spotify_playlists', 'in_apple_playlists']]
Y = spotify_2023_data['streams']
X['ones'] = np.ones(len(X),) #To do an interept 

threshold = 1e-6
step_size = 5e-9
theta, theta_prev = np.array(np.repeat(5,3)), np.ones(3,) #Randomized weights 

iter = 0
training_error = []
test_error = []
training_size = np.arange(1,len(Y)+1)
training_iterations = []
#TODO: 33 times and algorithm goes haywire
for i in training_size: #meant to show bias-variance tradeoff by changing number of training data
    if i % 2 == 0: continue
    X_train = X.iloc[:i]
    y_train = Y.iloc[:i]
    X_test = X.iloc[i:]
    y_test = Y.iloc[i:]

    while np.linalg.norm(theta - theta_prev) > threshold: #threshold mechanism used in textbook to determine when to stop. I have to use this, unfortunately. 
        theta_prev = theta
        gradient = mse_gradient(theta, X_train, y_train)
        theta = theta_prev - step_size * gradient
        if (np.isnan(theta)): print(theta)
        iter += 1

    print("i={}, results={}, mse={}".format(i, f(X_test, theta), mean_squared_error(y_test, f(X_test, theta))))
    print("theta={}".format(theta))
    print("iter=", iter)
    iter = 0
    training_error.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, f(X_train, theta)))
    test_error.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, f(X_test, theta)))
    training_iterations.append(i)
        
    theta, theta_prev = np.array(np.repeat(5,3)), np.ones(3,)
```

Regardless of what i values I use, it always seems to produce NaN values on the 33rd iteration. I've checked and this is probably because theta jumps to +infinity at this point. I've checked the data used, and there doesn't seem to be any missing data at all. What should I do to allow training to continue?

Comment: Could be a few things. What does your mse_gradient function look like? You may want to consider if there are any denominators that are zero which could propagate into your gradient.